# Stopping the MySQL BENCHMARK function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to stop executing the BENCHMARK function from within it? Basically, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(1000000, if(somecondition, STOP_BENCHMARK_SOMEHOW, somequery))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any need? you can only evaluate a scalar. You must be doing something pretty hefty for this to become something that takes a while. You might also want to consider reducing the number of iterations..

Comment: i just want to know if there is a way or if all the iterations are always executed no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to come up with a way to throw an error as a means of breaking out of the benchmarking loop, but it seems to turn errors into warnings, and continues the loop.

```
mysql> SET SQL_MODE=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO;
mysql> SET @a:=0;
mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100, IF((@a:=@a+1)>10, 1/0, SLEEP(1));

1 row in set, 90 warnings (10.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------+
| Level   | Code | Message       |
+---------+------+---------------+
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
| Warning | 1365 | Division by 0 |
. . .
```

The loop variable `@a` continues to increase, showing that the benchmark finished its full run:

```
mysql> select @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
|  100 |
+------+
```

The expression in the benchmark must be a scalar expression, so we can stop the benchmark by running a non-scalar subquery. But that terminates the benchmark and doesn't give the timing results.

```
mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100, if((@a:=@a+1)>10, (SELECT host FROM mysql.user), SLEEP(1)));
... about 10 seconds goes by ...
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I think you're going to have to use a real benchmarking tool instead of using only MySQL's built-in `BENCHMARK()` function.

Comment: _"The loop variable @a continues to increase, showing that the benchmark finished its full run:"_, yes... but if you're doing something horrible in there (the only reason for this I can think of), it seems like you've only evaluated the function 10 times and raised an error 90, which means it'll be quicker and you're able to control the iterations whilst executing.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you gave some good ideas I can think about now